# Extract data from index in new column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

How do I extract data based on index values in different columns?

So far I was able to extract data based on index number in the same column (block of 5).

**The Dataframe looks like this:**

```
3017     39517.3886
3018     39517.4211
3019     39517.4683
3020     39517.5005
3021     39517.5486
5652     39628.1622
5653     39628.2104
5654     39628.2424
5655     39628.2897
5656     39628.3229
5677     39629.2020
5678     39629.2342
5679     39629.2825
5680     39629.3304
5681     39629.3628
```

Where the data extracted in col are +/- 2 rows around the index value

I would like to have something that looks more like this:

```
  3017-3021   5652-5656   5677-5681
1 39517.3886  39628.1622  39629.2020
2 39517.4211  39628.2104  39629.2342
3 39517.4683  39628.2424  39629.2825
4 39517.5005  39628.2897  39629.3304
5 39517.5486  39628.3229  39629.3628
```

and so on depending on the number of data that I want to extract.

The code I'm using to extract data based on index is:

```
## find index based on the first 0 of a 000 - 111 list
a = stim_epoc[1:]
ss = [(num+1) for num,i in enumerate(zip(stim_epoc,a)) if i == (0,1)]

## extract data from a df (GCamp_ps) based on the previous index 'ss'
fin = [i for x in ss for i in range(x-2, x + 2 + 1) if i in range(len(GCaMP_ps))]
df = time_fip.loc[np.unique(fin)]
print(df)
```

Comment: `Where the index is +/- 2 raw.` What does this mean? That you want separate groups when the index changes by more than 2?

Comment: You can add the index as a column using **df["index_col"] = df.index**, and then work from there.

Comment: Sorry guys I wasn't clear enough. I meant that the values extracted based on index are +/- 2 raws around the index value. I would like to group the 'blocks' extracted in different columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form groups of 5 consecutive rows (since you pull +/-2 rows from a center). Then create the column and index labels and `pivot`

```
df = df.reset_index()
s = df.index//5   # If always 5 consecutive values. I.e. +/-2 rows from a center.    

df['col'] = df.groupby(s)['index'].transform(lambda x: '-'.join(map(str, x.agg(['min', 'max']))))
df['idx'] = df.groupby(s).cumcount()

df.pivot(index='idx', columns='col', values=0)  # Assuming column named `0`
```

#### Output:

```
col   3017-3021   5652-5656   5677-5681
idx                                    
0    39517.3886  39628.1622  39629.2020
1    39517.4211  39628.2104  39629.2342
2    39517.4683  39628.2424  39629.2825
3    39517.5005  39628.2897  39629.3304
4    39517.5486  39628.3229  39629.3628
```

Comment: Clever solution! I like it!

Comment: Good solution - I have a UDF using a graph and connected components to accomplish the same task. For safety, maybe add a sort at the beginning? I know the data he gave was already sorted, but if it isn't it'll blow this up.

Comment: @flyingmeatball. Yes, I think if all groups are guaranteed to not overlap, then sorting is appropriate and safe. If, however, the data are generated by taking some index and then +/2, you could imagine somehow sampling 3000 [2998-3002] as the center then 3001 [2999-3003]. In that case sorting would break the groupings (and my `diff` grouping will fail), while `df.reset_index().index//5` will still preserve the groupings, and allows for groups to overlap, so long as they appear together.